# What is the difference between pyspark.sql.udf and pyspark.sql.functions.udf?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I can import udf in two ways:
`pyspark.sql.udf`
and
`pyspark.sql.functions.udf`

I can use both to define  udfs on a dataframe. What is the difference between the two and when to prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did my research in pyspark2.4.0.

Here is the source code for both:

[pyspark.sql.functions.udf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/functions.html#udf)

This is a wrapper *function* (also called decorator). It has a lot of documentation and a bit of code wrapping of the `_create_udf` internal method.

#### This is what you want to use to create User Defined Functions.

Then we have [pyspark.sql.udf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/udf.html).

This is a *python module* (a whole file) and apart from the 3 `register` functions, it has no documentation and does not seem to be for direct use.

The `_create_udf` is defined here, as well as the `UserDefinedFunction` class. It just seems to be the file where the internals of the **UDF** class are created.

Hope this helped, I'd be happy to answer any additional questions in the comments.

Comment: No problem, I was happy to.